# Loop and Split Child Nodes into Multiple Child Nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is my input XML that I need to transform using XSLT 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <id>1234</id>
        <loc>New York</loc>
        <Days>1</Days>
        <StartDate>2019-01-26</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <Batch>A</Batch>
        <Days>3</Days>
        <Units>2</Units>
        <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Current Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <id>1234</id>
        <loc>New York</loc>
        <Days>1</Days>
        <StartDate>2019-01-26</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-02</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-03</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>3</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-04</StartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <id>1234</id>
        <loc>New York</loc>
        <Days>1</Days>
        <StartDate>2019-01-26</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-02/StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>3</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-03</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <id>2345</id>
        <loc>Boston</loc>
        <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <StartDate>2019-02-02/StartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

My requirements are

a.) If element `<Batch>` is not present in a child node, that child node should be copied as it appears in the XML. In the above XML, the first worker child node should be copied as it appears in the XML as it doesn’t have `<Batch>` element in it.

b.) If element `<Batch>` is present in a child node, that child node needs to be split into multiple child nodes based on following two conditions

1.)  Number of child nodes need to be created as many number of times as the value of element `<Days>`. In this case, `<Days>` has 3 as a value, so 3 child nodes need to be created and each one of those child node should have `<StartDate>` incremented by one and create a new element `<RecordNumber>` that should hold the value of that loop.

2.) Child node again needs to be split based on the value of element `<Units>`. In above XML, `<Units>` is 2, so two times  child node needs to be created and `<StartDate>` needs to be incremented by one each time it creates and and create a new element `<RecordNumber>` that should hold the value of that loop

Current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Workers/Worker[exists(Batch)]">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="counter" select="Days"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Records" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$start to $counter">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$Records" mode="replicate">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Workers/Worker" mode="replicate">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <Worker>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
            </id>
            <loc>
                <xsl:value-of select="loc"/>
            </loc>
            <RecordNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="$data"/>
            </RecordNumber>
            <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
            <StartDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(StartDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * $data"/>
            </StartDate>
        </Worker>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Issues:

1. Value of `<StartDate>` is wrong - seems like actual `<StartDate>` is missing
2. XSLT is not splitting child node based on  at all.
3. `<Worker>` child node should appear 6 times in expected output where as i get only 4 now.

Can someone help me fix the issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected output I see that you need 2 loops **in a sequence**:

- the first - executed `Days` number of times,
- the second - executed `Units` number of times,

both for consecutive dates, starting from the input date.

Note also that in `for-each` loop the **context item** is changed, so in
case of both `for-each` loops, the context item is the current numer of
execution, taken form `select` attribute.

This is the reason that in each loop, when calling `Worker` template,
`dayNo` parameter has been given as a **dot** and **currElem** is
just the element, for which `Worker[Batch]` template was called.

As far as the output `StartDate` is concerned, the `dayTimeDuration` must
be added `$dayNo - 1` number of times.

Another useful additions / changes are:

- `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` at the beginning, causing "better"
  indentation of the output.
- `<xsl:sequence .../>` - a shorter form to copy source elements to the output.
  It is also worth to note that it runs much quicker and consumes much
  less memory.
- I deleted some variables used 1 time only.
- You used a variable called `data`. IMHO this name is "too general",
  so I changed it to `currElem` (the current element).

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Worker[Batch]">
    <xsl:variable name="currElem" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to Days">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$currElem" mode="replicate">
        <xsl:with-param name="dayNo" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to Units">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$currElem" mode="replicate">
        <xsl:with-param name="dayNo" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Worker" mode="replicate">
    <xsl:param name="dayNo"/>
    <Worker>
      <xsl:sequence select="id, loc"/>
      <RecordNumber><xsl:value-of select="$dayNo"/></RecordNumber>
      <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
      <StartDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(StartDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * ($dayNo - 1)"/>
      </StartDate>
    </Worker>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/asnmyP/1

The first version is under http://xsltransform.net/asnmyP (if you wanted
to compare them).

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo. While i'm trying to understand your code, I found an issue with the output that it returns. Value of `<Units>` is 2, so `<Worker>` element needs to be created only two times. Now that it returns 3 times. Expected output should have only 6 `<Worker>` nodes. Is that a problem with Outer for-each?

Comment: Your input XML contains *<Units>2</Units>* (how many times execute the outer loop) and *<Days>3</Days>* (how many times execute the inner loop (for consecutive dates)).
So my script generates the expected result. On the other hand, it is a bit weird concept to generate **exactly the same content** multiple times, but this is how I understood your question. Or maybe results of outer loop should differ in some respect?

Comment: Sorry to have you confused with my requirements. Let me take an example to explain my requirement. If value of `<Units>` is 9 and `<Days>`is 2, `<Worker>` element needs to be created 11 times .. now that `<Worker>` creates 18 times because of the reason you stated -outer loop executes the number of times the value of `<Units>`. Another example .. if Units is 5 and Days is 10 - 15 times Worker element need to be created.. Reason why same content needs to be generated multiple times is the requirement of a downstream system as they need to process the RecordNumber and StartDates one by one.

Comment: I corrected the solution, based on explanation in your recent comment. Now it should be OK.